# Visual Studio 2010 includes MFC even though empty console application is specified (C++)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I've spent most of my day trying to figure out why this error is occurring but it continues to mystify me.

I created a console application in Visual C++ and specified it to be empty. After putting all of my source in the virtual folder and compiling it an error occurred:

> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
>
> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
>
> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

Strange error indeed, because I never included any MFC files. So I remedied the situation by specifying "/MT" in the code generation settings.

This worked well...until I decided to include "Windows.h", which spawned this error:

> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h(16): fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include windows.h
>
> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h(16): fatal   error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include windows.h

I've tried everything I could think of, including recreating the project with and without precompiled headers, a Win32 app rather than console, and a WxWidget app. All of these apps seemingly try to include MFC even though I never specified. Can anyone shed some light on this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Well, what does your code look like?  What headers are you including?  Can you demonstrate a minimal repro?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VWsTC6vc

This looks like the problem. I'm using the CMarkup library for XML work. Apparently it uses Cstrings, curiosity has me wondering if it will work without MFC included, but I have no idea how to make that so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find out what's including the MFC headers - the `/showIncludes` option may help with that.

Which in the IDE project property page is under:

```
C/C++ | Advanced | Show Includes
```

Once you know who is including them you can make a decision on how to address the problem - you might simply be able to remove an errant `#include`, but it might require jettisoning a library you're using that's dependent on MFC.

Comment: An external library, or more so source, is the problem. I'm tracking down how to specify STL strings vs MFC CStrings in the CMarkup library, which is what I'm using. However navigating their documentation is proving less than developer friendly.

Comment: Problem solved, CMarkup was unnecessarily obscure in the matter. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `CString` without the MFC library by using `#include <atlstr.h>`.  Microsoft broke out several utility classes from the MFC library back in VS 2003 (maybe VS 2002).  If `CString` is all that CMarkup uses, it should hopefully be an easy change (almost certainly easier than changing to use `std::string`).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure 'USE of MFC' is in 'Use MFC in a Shared DLL' setting.  That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

**If MFC is required,**  set the following values ( Debug/Win32 ):

Configuration Properties > General :

> Use of MFC : Use MFC in a Shared DLL

Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation :

> Runtime Library : /MDd

**If MFC is not required,** and only standard window libraries are required, keep the setting as below.

Configuration Properties > General :

> Use of MFC : Use Standard Windows Libraries

Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation :

> Runtime Library : /MTd